# How to use nock to intercept requests regardless of body

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, mocha.js, nock

I'm trying to use nock in my tests to intercept the request calls i'm making from the native `https` module in Node.js.  `I'm using Promise.all` to make two requests to the external server.  I want my tests to intercept the calls, and check some of the form fields to make sure they're filled in as i want.

I have my class setup below (kept the most relevant parts of code in):

```
const archiver = require('archiver');
const { generateKeyPairSync } = require('crypto');
const FormData = require('form-data');
const fs = require('fs');
const https = require('https');

class Platform {
  constructor() {
    this.FILESTORE_USERNAME = process.env.FILESTORE_USERNAME;
    this.FILESTORE_PASSWORD = process.env.FILESTORE_PASSWORD;
  }

  store(serviceName) {
    const { publicKey, privateKey } = this._generateKeys();

    return Promise.all([this._postKey(publicKey), this._postKey(privateKey)])
      .then(() => {
        return this._zipKeys(publicKey, privateKey, serviceName);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        throw err;
      });
  }

  _postKey(key) {
    const options = this._getOptions();
    const keyName = (key.search(/(PUBLIC)/) !== -1) ? 'publicKey' : 'privateKey';
    const form = new FormData();
    form.append('file', key);
    form.append('Name', keyName);
    form.append('MimeMajor', 'application');
    form.append('MimeMinor', 'x-pem-file');
    form.append('Extension', (keyName == 'publicKey') ? 'pub' : '');
    form.append('FileClass', 'MFS::File');
    options.headers = form.getHeaders();
    options.headers.Authorization = 'Basic ' + Buffer.from(this.FILESTORE_USERNAME + ':' + this.FILESTORE_PASSWORD).toString('base64');

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      let post = https.request(options, (res) => {
        let data = '';
        if (res.statusCode < 200 || res.statusCode > 299) {
          reject(new Error('File Storage API returned a status code outside of acceptable range: ' + res.statusCode));
        } else {
          res.setEncoding('utf8');
          res.on('data', (chunk) => {
            data += chunk;
          });

          res.on('error', (err) => {
            reject(err);
          });

          res.on('end', () => {
            if (data) {
              resolve(JSON.parse(data));
            } else {
              resolve();
            }
          });
        }
      });
      post.on('error', (err) => {
        reject(err);
      });
      form.pipe(post);
      post.end();

    });
  }

  _getOptions() {
    return {
      hostname: 'api.example.com',
      path: '/media/files/',
      method: 'POST',
    };
  }
}

module.exports = Platform;
```

And then, my testing code looks like the below.  I'm using mocha, sinon, chai, sinon-chai and nock.

```
const Platform = require('/usr/src/app/api/Services/Platform');
const crypto = require('crypto');
const fs = require('fs');
const nock = require('nock');
const yauzl = require('yauzl');

describe('Platform', function() {
  let platform;
  beforeEach(() => {
    platform = new Platform();
  });
  afterEach(() => {
    const list = fs.readdirSync('/usr/src/app/api/Services/data/');
    list.forEach((file) => {
      fs.unlink('/usr/src/app/api/Services/data/' + file, (err) => {
        if (err) throw err;
      });
    });
    nock.cleanAll();
  });
  after(() => {
    nock.restore();
  });
  describe('store', function() {
    it('should post each generated key to an external storage place', async function() {
      this.timeout(5000);
      // const stub = sinon.stub(platform, '_postKey').resolves();
      const scope = nock('https://api.example.com')
        .persist()
        .post('/media/files/', (body) => {
          // console.log(body);
        })
        .reply(200);

      let serviceName = 'test';
      let actual = await platform.store(serviceName)
        .catch((err) => {
          (() => { throw err; }).should.not.throw();
        });

      console.log(scope);
      // expect(stub.callCount).to.equal(2);
      expect(actual).to.be.a('string');
      expect(actual).to.include(serviceName + '.zip');
      // stub.reset();

    });
  });
});
```

The problem I am coming across is this error that is thrown when running my tests:

> AssertionError: expected [Function] to not throw an error but 'Error:
>   Nock: No match for request {\n  "method": "POST",\n  "url":
>   "https://api.example.com/media/files/",\n  "headers": {\n
>   "content-type": "multipart/form-data;
>   boundary=--------------------------363749230271182821931703",\n
>   "authorization": "Basic abcdef1224u38454857483hfjdhjgtuyrwyt="\n  },\n
>   "body":
>   "----------------------------363749230271182821931703\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\"\r\n\r\n-----BEGIN PUBLIC
>   KEY-----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\nDWXpfMJUU8TQuLGWZQaGJc8CAwEAAQ==\n-----END
>   PUBLIC
>   KEY-----\n\r\n----------------------------363749230271182821931703\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data;
>   name=\"Name\"\r\n\r\npublicKey\r\n----------------------------363749230271182821931703\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data;
>   name=\"MimeMajor\"\r\n\r\napplication\r\n----------------------------363749230271182821931703\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data;
>   name=\"MimeMinor\"\r\n\r\nx-pem-file\r\n----------------------------363749230271182821931703\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data;
>   name=\"Extension\"\r\n\r\npub\r\n----------------------------363749230271182821931703\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data;
>   name=\"FileClass\"\r\n\r\nMFS::File\r\n----------------------------363749230271182821931703--\r\n"\n}'
>   was thrown

I take it it's because nock expects me to fake out the body for the request to get a correct match?  Is there a way of just looking for requests made to that address, regardless of the body, so I can do my own tests or whatever.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the `post` method of a Nock Scope is passed a second argument, it is used to match against the body of the request.

[Docs for specifying the request body](https://github.com/nock/nock#specifying-request-body)

In your test, you're passing a function as the second argument, but not returning `true` so Nock is not considering it a match.

From the docs:

> Function: nock will evaluate the function providing the request body
>   object as first argument. Return true if it should be considered a
>   match

Since your goal is to assert form fields on the request, your best approach would be to leave the function there, do your assertions where the `// console.log(body);` line is, but add `return true;` to the end of the function.

You could also return `true` or `false` depending on if your form fields match your assertions, but in my experience it makes the error output from the test convoluted. My preference is to use standard `chai` `expect()` calls and let the assertions bubble errors before Nock continues with request matching.